# Closed subsets of Souslin orders

Tags: set-theory, general-topology

A total order without end-points is *Souslin* if it is complete, non-separable and ccc. Such orders may or may not exist but when they do, there can be a vast zoo of them.

Can we get consistent examples of Souslin orders with a stronger property demanding that closed intervals are second-countable or at least separable?

Comment: This question belongs on Math-Stack Exchange instead. It is not too difficult to show that every complete separable totally ordered set without endpoints is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, the countable chain condition is truly necessary.

Comment: I am asking only for separability of closed proper intervals.

Comment: If you are looking at proper intervals, then you can also include the long lines but that is it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to imply.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29

Comment: Yes, I know what is the long line yet I don't know how is related to the question.

Comment: The long line pointing to the left, the long line pointing to the right, the two way long line, and the real numbers are the only complete total orders without endpoints such that every proper closed interval is separable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix a cofinal well-ordered subset and a coinitial anti-well-ordered subset of your Souslin line. These subsets are countable, because of the ccc.  So the whole Souslin line is the union of countably many closed proper subintervals.